# SBOMAILER configuration sap business one

Tags: gmail, sapb1

I'm just curious about the SBO Mailer and gmail smtp server setting.

How can I send email directly from sap users email id instead of only using the sbomailer username email id?

Thanks.
Regards

Answer (score 0):

1. To open the SAP Business One Service Manager window, in the
   Microsoft Windows task bar, double-click the Service Manager icon
   [image]

Alternatively, in Windows, choose Start → All Programs → SAP Business One → Server Tools → Service Manager.

2. From the Service dropdown list, select Job Service - Mailer.

[image]

3. Choose (Play) [image] and select the
   Start when operating system starts checkbox.
4. Define your mail settings;

   In the SAP Business One Service Manager window, choose the Settings
   button.
        The General Settings window appears. [image]

   - SMTP Server — Enter the name or IP address of your outgoing mail
     server. To make changes in this field later, you must stop the Mailer
     service.
   - SMTP Port — Specify the port number for mail services.
   - Encoding — Select the language for e-mail text.
   - HTML direction right-to-left — Select this checkbox if you are using
     a right-to-left language to define the direction of the e-mail text.
   - Include Subject in Message Body — Select this checkbox to include the
     subject line in the body of the message.
   - Fax Settings — Select the required fax service. (not required for you)
   - Scheduled Report Settings - Specify the required information for
     configuring SBO Mailer for report scheduling and mailing. (Not required for you)
5. Connect to the database:

   - In the SAP Business One Service Manager window, from the Service dropdown list, select SBO Mailer, and then choose the Connection button.

[image]

In the Connection Settings Window, do the following:

- To connect to a database, specify a valid user name and password.
- To use Windows Authentication, select the Use Trusted Connection checkbox.
- Choose the OK button.

  Select a database by clicking the database button
- Select the database you want to enable mailing services for and then choose the OK button.

Set the Mail processing schedules:

- By Intervals — Sets mail and fax processing to start regularly every x hours and y minutes.
- On Specific Date — Defines mail and fax processing for a specific date and time.
- Daily — Sets mail and fax processing for a fixed hour of each day.
- Weekly — Sets mail and fax processing for a fixed hour on a fixed day of each week.
- Monthly — Sets mail and fax processing for a fixed hour on a fixed day of each month.

[image]

You can now proceed to define the email signature settings. To access the email signature settings, from the SAP Business One Main Menu, choose Administration → System Initialization → E-Mail Settings.

IMPORTANT: Make sure the email you use in the mailer also exists in the following area:

Administration → System Initialization → Company Details → At the bottom there is an email field. it must be the same with the SBO Mailer set email

Comment: Thank you enshadowed_ . When i send an email , the email is sent from sbomailer email address and not from user email defined in User. How can be that? Thanks.

Comment: The email is defined in the Mailer settings and in the following: 
IMPORTANT: Make sure the email you use in the mailer also exists in the following area:

Administration → System Initialization → Company Details → At the bottom there is an email field. it must be the same with the SBO Mailer set email. You can't set it up to be per user. For that you will need to develop a custom addon. We have an addon if you are interested.

Comment: Ok, maybe you can send me something ? Thank you.

Comment: I can send you some of its "features" but basically it uses the outlook on each PC to send emails automatically through SAP (so basically the default account in Outlook) feel free to PM me your email if you want to know more

Answer (score 0):

This is a Gmail behavior.  The solution is to use the gmail SMTP RELAY instead of authenticating using a gmail account.

Configure IP address based authentication in gmail using your external IP address or address ranges.

in SAP B1 use  smtp-relay.gmail.com on port 25 and anonymous authentication (no TLS) for the SMTP server.

for info on setting up gmail smtp realay see -https://support.google.com/a/answer/2956491?hl=en

1. Sign in to your Google Admin console.
   Sign in using an administrator account, not your current account 
   From the Admin console Home page, go to Apps G Suite Gmail Advanced settings.
   Tip: To see Advanced settings, scroll to the bottom of the Gmail page.
2. On the left, select the top-level organization. See Tailor advanced settings for Gmail for more details.
   Note: You can configure the SMTP relay service setting for the top-level organization only. You can view the setting from the sub-organization level when it's added, but you can't add, edit, or delete the setting from the sub-organization level.
3. Scroll to the SMTP relay service setting in the Routing section, hover over the setting, and click Configure. If the setting is already configured, hover over the setting and click Edit or Add another.